# Finding a Payment Gateway?

Tags: payment-gateway

I have a client who would like to sell glass pipes online. The problem I run into is with the payment gateway. Glass pipes fall into two categories `drug paraphernalia` or `tobacco product`. This leads me to here and asking: Does anyone know of a payment gateway that will process payments for glass pipes?

Note: Doing some Google searching I read that Authorize.net will accept tobacco but when I spoke with them they said they do not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glass pipes and other tobacco or drug paraphernalia products are "high risk products." There are other products that are classified as high risk. Any high, or even medium risk products, many companies, such as Authorize.net or PayPal, won't touch these accounts.

What you must do is find a payment gateway/merchant account that will work with high risk accounts. These accounts can and do charge higher rates than low risk products.

The one I use and recommend is [Pathway Payments](http://www.pathwaypayments.com/partner/ubhape2.html). The rates are great and the customer service is outstanding.

*Disclaimer: If you contact and use Pathway Payments by the link provided I do receive a commission. Please note that I do recommend Pathway Payments regardless of any affiliation.*

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way you will get a guaranteed answer on this is to talk to the reps at different payment gateway companies and explain your business to them over the phone. Explain that you only sell legal products for tobacco use, and that your site says the products are explicitly for tobacco use only (I'm assuming it does). If you talk to them in a professional mannor I'm sure you will find one to accomodate your business - try all the big guys like Paypal, Authorize, Paypoint, etc or any others that will work with your application. Good luck!